# system.copy gives reference to array pascal

Tags: reference, dynamic-arrays, freepascal

I'm writing program that should solve matrix equasions using Cramer's rule and I have such function for this:

```
function solveKramers(AMatr: Matrix; BMatr: Vector): vector;
var
    detA: real;
    solvingMatrix: Matrix;
    i, j: Integer;
begin
  detA := getDet(AMatr);

  if (not (detA = 0) or not (Length(AMatr) = Length(BMatr))) then begin
    SetLength(Result, Length(BMatr));

    for i := 0 to High(BMatr) do begin

      solvingMatrix := system.copy(AMatr);

      for j := 0 to High(solvingMatrix) do begin
        solvingMatrix[j, i] := BMatr[j];
      end;

      Result[i] := getDet(solvingMatrix) / detA;

    end;
    Exit;
  end;

end;
```

I created `matrix = array of vector` and `vector = array of real`
And when I try using it, `solvingMatrix := system.copy(AMatr);` creates reference to AMatr instead of creating copy of this matrix.

Comment: You do actually get a copy of the array. But it's just the outer array. The issue here is that the language does not support multidimensional arrays. These are jagged arrays, in this case a 1D array whose elements are also 1D arrays. Jagged arrays in Delphi are the wrong data type for matrix work.

Comment: BTW, Cramer's rule is generally not a good algorithm to solve matrix equations in practical situations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for info, I was using Cramer's rule just because we had such task, but thanks for all. Also, can you suggest a type that would make work with matrixes easier?

Comment: I'd use a different language if I were you, and could. But what you really want is a multidimensional array which Delphi doesn't have. You can fake it using a 1d array and handle the 2d indexing yourself `(j * nCol + i)`. If you are just doing an educational tasks then what you have done in your answer is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know how this thing works, but I solved it by copying each row separetly(the weird thing is that I did simillar in getDet function but it worked alright)
The code that I added looks like this:

```
for j := 0 to High(AMatr) do begin
  solvingMatrix[j] := system.copy(AMatr[j]);
end;
```